# Who can i construct a spreadsheet object with an array PHP

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I try to modify a excel.xlsx file with PHPSpreadsheet.
No problem with the reading functionnality:
`$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($filename); $rows = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();`
I mofify some data in the array: `$rows`
Now I want to construct a spreadsheet object with my modified $rows, anyone know the method and class that should be used please?

I tried several methods from the documentation, but I admit that I do not understand this documentation precisely.